# Is it possible to restrict ngDialog to allow only one open modal?

Tags: angularjs

We're using ngDialog to open a modal box. While there will be many links to open modals, we only want one open at a time. Is there a way to do this using the ngDialog parameters?

The dialog can take a few seconds to load, and meanwhile users may click on a second link.

Comment: what you can do is close the earlier one before opening the another...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've added ngDialog.closeAll(); before it actually does the open. This doesn't seem to work if you click on multiple links at more or less the same time. I'm a newbie to angular so maybe I'm doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The ngDialog open function returns an object containing the ID of the opened dialog.
You can save last opened dialog ID and use it to verify the dialog is not open before opening a new one.

Looks like this:

```
var dialog = {};
function openDialog(){
   if(!ngDialog.isOpen(dialog.id)){
      dialog = ngDialog.open({
         template: 'views/dialog.html',
         controller: 'someCtrl',
         scope: scope
      });
   }
};
```

Also, if you would like to make this behaviour the default one for ngDialog, I'd suggest reading about [decorators](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#decorator).